# Memory + dynamic programming or recursion

Tags: c++, recursion, dynamic

Problem is that i have 64 megabytes on solution,so i can use only 16,777,216 int numbers.

But for answer i must use 33,333,333 numbers,so some answers will not be considered.

Actually, problem is [this](https://www.e-olymp.com/en/problems/236).

By the way, i had my own code instead:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int sq(int x) {
return (long long)(x*x) %(1000000);
}

int  func(int x) {
if (x==0)
    return 3;
else {
        return ( sq(func(x-1))+2)%(1000000);
}
}

int main()
{
/*const int num=16 777 216;
    int* arr=new int [num];
                            arr[0]=3;
                        for (int i=1;i<num;i++)
                            arr[i]=((arr[i-1]%(1000000))*(arr[i-1])%(1000000)+2)%(1000000);*/

    int t,rez;
    int n;
    cin>>t;
    for (int p=0;p<t;p++) {
                    cin>>n;
                    if (n%3!=0) {
                        rez=0;
                    } else {
                       // rez=arr[n/3-1];
                       rez=func(n/3-1);
                            }
                            cout<<rez<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

In comments there is second solution.

I can do it with recursion, but i have limit in 1 second.

So what code would be OK?

Comment: Not doing your homework.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Looks like another stoopid online code judge challenge.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ So why u comment this,if u think its stupid?

Comment: @Pyroarsonist I didn't say that your question is stupid (though it's low quality, incomplete and missing a [MCVE]), but competing at online code judges is in general. We can't tell you much about their inner workings or hidden testcases here.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Thanks,i would reckon on it further.

Comment: Might be worth tidying up the code if you want more people to look at it.

Comment: *What* do you have to do in 1 sec?  Each test case?  All test cases?  All numbers up to 10^9?

Comment: @Prune Each test must be in 1 sec.

Comment: No problem; my answer below has an overhead of finding the initial set of responses; after that, handling each case will be a matter of a few milliseconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need anywhere near that many entries (10^9 / 3).  Note that you need only the values mod 10^6.  You have a recurrence relationship among these:

```
a[n] = a[n-1]^2 + 2
```

Each value depends only on the previous one, so there will be a simple sequence of numbers.  The relation will have a period of no more than 10^6.  Since they're all odd, the maximum length is cut in half.

As it turns out, the sequence repeats after 5003 terms, with a period of 5000: 3, 11, 123 do not appear later in the sequence.

So, forget that huge array.  Compute the 5003 terms you need.  Now for any input number **N**, you have 3 cases:

```
(1) N is not divisible by 3: return 0
else N is divisible by 3; call the quotient M
(2) M <= 3: return arr[M]
(3) else, get the needed subscript as m = ((M-3) mod 5000) + 3;
       return arr[m]
```

You can now handle arbitrarily large input.